# Python HTML Minimizer

Tags: python, html, minimize

I have a cherrypy web server that uses larges amounts of HTML  data.  Is there anyway in Python to minimize the HTML so that all comments, spaces, ext, are removed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not what you mean, but: [Gzip](http://www.cherrypy.org/wiki/GzipFilter#Gzip). (Assuming you aren't already serving through a compressing front-end.) Compression will zip away whitespace to almost nothing; unless you have excessively large comments this will be more effective than minification.

Answer (score 2):

there are bindings to tidy for python, called mxTidy from eGenix (Marc André Lemburg)

Answer (score 0):

[HTML Tidy's libtidy](http://tidy.sourceforge.net/) doesn't seem to have python bindings (bit it does have perl and c++ etc), but ought to be easy to run as an exe in a pipe.

Or ideally, use it to 'tidy' all static html files once so they don't need to be tidied each time they are served.

Comment: That page links to a *TidyLib Python wrapper*: http://utidylib.berlios.de/ but I don't know if it minifies.